# SQL Server - Correlated Subqueries / Self Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, self-join, correlated-subquery

A select statement returning the name, city, and state of each vendor that's located in a unique city and state (i.e., excludes vendors that have same city and state with another vendor)

```
SELECT 
    VendorName, VendorCity, VendorState
FROM 
    Vendors
WHERE 
    VendorState + VendorCity NOT IN (SELECT VendorState + VendorCity
                                     FROM Vendors
                                     GROUP BY VendorState + VendorCity
                                     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
ORDER BY 
    VendorState, VendorCity;
```

Alternate answer

```
SELECT 
    VendorName, VendorCity, VendorState
FROM 
    Vendors AS Vendors_Main
WHERE 
    VendorCity + VendorState NOT IN (SELECT VendorCity + VendorState
                                     FROM Vendors AS Vendors_Sub
                                     WHERE Vendors_Sub.VendorID <> Vendors_Main.VendorID)
ORDER BY 
    VendorState, VendorCity;
```

I understand the first answer, but not the alternate query. Point of confusion: wouldn't the line below return 0 rows since they're referencing the same table without an additional where clause?

```
WHERE Vendors_Sub.VendorID <> Vendors_Main.VendorID)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WHERE Vendors_Sub.VendorID <> Vendors_Main.VendorID)` doesn't compare the same row of the same table.

A *correlated subquery* is logically executed once for each row in the outer query, in your case it checks for rows with the same `VendorCity`/ `VendorState` combination, but different `VendorIDs`.

In fact I would prefer a direct translation into a correlated `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT VendorName, VendorCity, VendorState
FROM Vendors AS Vendors_Main
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (
   SELECT *
   FROM Vendors AS Vendors_Sub
   WHERE Vendors_Sub.VendorCity  = Vendors_Main.VendorCity  -- same city
     AND Vendors_Sub.VendorState = Vendors_Main.VendorState -- same state
     AND Vendors_Sub.VendorID   <> Vendors_Main.VendorID    -- different vendor
 )
ORDER BY VendorState, VendorCity;
```

This prevents false positives like `'state' + 'acity'` vs. `'statea' + 'city'` which both concatenate to '`stateacity'` and works for any kind of datatype.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  VendorName ,
        VendorCity ,
        VendorState
FROM    Vendors AS Vendors_Main
WHERE   VendorCity + VendorState NOT IN 
    (
        SELECT  VendorCity + VendorState
        FROM    Vendors AS Vendors_Sub
        WHERE   Vendors_Sub.VendorID <> Vendors_Main.VendorID
    )
ORDER BY VendorState ,VendorCity;
```

The sub query

```
SELECT  VendorCity + VendorState
FROM    Vendors AS Vendors_Sub
WHERE   Vendors_Sub.VendorID <> Vendors_Main.VendorID
```

will return all existing combinations of `vendorCity + vendorState` for each row in the main query excluding those with the same id. Imagin the subquery as a function being called for each row in the main query.

If `WHERE   Vendors_Sub.VendorID <> Vendors_Main.VendorID` was not there each main query row would match to itself in the subquery and the whole query would return no rows because none of the combinations would be unique.